# Centering an image, horizontally

Tags: android, imageview, nine-patch

I'm just starting on my first Android app. I'm working in Android Studio, and my initial problem is to display a customer logo across the top of the first page.

I've figured out how to turn the logo into a .9.png, and to load it into the project at the various required resolutions using the android-drawable-importer plugin.

Now my problem is simply getting the image to scale properly, across my display.

Currently, I'm playing with a LinearLayout, with an ImageView taking up the top area of the display:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="12"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/mylogo"
        />

    <!-- ... -->

</LinearLayout>
```

With that, my logo takes up the top 1/6th of the display, centered horizontally, but it's not stretching to fill the full width of the display.  If I add android:scaleType="fitXY", it scales to fill horizontally, but it also scales vertically, resulting in my not seeing the top and bottom of the logo.

Is there a way of displaying an image so that it fits vertically, and fills horizontally?

---

I'm editing this, to expand its scope, a bit.  It might be that I'm too focused on making a 9-patch work, and that there are simpler solutions to my problem.

What I need is pretty simple - I want a logo displayed in the top area of the page, centered horizontally, with the logo not distorted by x- or y-axis scaling, but with the background color extending to the edges of the display, horizontally.

If a nine-patch won't do this, perhaps something else will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a logo with a transparent background and then just set the `android:background` of your `ImageView` to the color you need? That way you have higher control of the logo display?

Also, have you tried experimenting with other [scale types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)?:

Try setting the `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and your image should be displayed centered in parent and also scaled to fill as much as possible of the available space.

If the image is still incorrectly scaled, you can also set the [android:adjustViewVounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) parameter in order for it to better fit your needs

Comment: The problem with setting the background is that the two sides of the image have different colors. I've been playing with tiling the image between two views with solid background colors, but I've not been able to get it to work.

Comment: That looks like it works. Or, at least, it looks good in the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:scaleType="fitXY". This attribute is necessary for 9patch to work. Also, here are some other things to keep in mind when using 9patch.

1) Reference the drawable with the name but don't include .9.png (auto-complete in eclipse will take care of this if you are still using Eclipse that is *tisk-tisk*)

2) Make sure you only have 1 image under the main /drawable folder (not a version for each dpi folder)

3) The image must be specified using :background, not :src (this got me stuck for a while)

```
android:background="@drawable/splash_logo"
```

4) Make sure the image and layout that contains it are using:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Hopefully this helps with your height scaling, cheers!

Comment: With that, the image is filling the area, but it's not scaling at all.

Comment: Then problem is your 9patch. You probably did not apply it correctly. Try the logo without your 9patch edits. For a general logo, 9patch is probably not applicable. Use 9patch for background frames or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/your_logo_image"
        android:background="@color/your_logo_image_background_color"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

This is kind of workaround, an "ugly" solution.

I agree with [porfoliobuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2127950/portfoliobuilder), that the nine-patch image is probably not the best approach for logos.